# Jenkins Pipeline: How to hide password/string in console logs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline, which does the following:

- checks out another repo into workspace
- in the pipeline it executes a shell script which: cd into that repo, then executes a python script, which takes in the account name (svc_account) and the password/token as args.

These passwords/token are passed into the jenkinsfile from the credentials (commons), ie:

```
    def setupUserPWdBindingVars(credentialsIdToUse = credID) {
    this.steps.withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: credentialsIdToUse, usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
        this.env.USERNAME = this.env.USERNAME
        this.env.PASSWORD = this.env.PASSWORD
    }
}
```

from jenkinsfile:

```
        stage('Run shell script') {
        steps {
            script {
                commons.setupUserPWBindingVars(credID)
                catchError(stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                                          withEnv([
                        "USERNAME=${USERNAME}",
                        "PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}",
                    ]) {
                        commons.executeShellScriptFromFile('run_shell_script.sh')
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

from run_shell_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash -xe
cd ${WORKSPACE}/my_repo
python3 running_myScript.py ${USERNAME} ${PASSWORD}
```

The problem that we are seeing is that when we open the console logs, we can see the passwords/tokens. ie, console output:

```
12:38:15  + python3 running_myScript.py  svc_account '<<my password/token exposed>>'
```

Comment: `running_myScript.py` should be fixed to read credentials from environment variables instead of CLI args. That would be more secure, fix this issue, and involve cleaner code.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your issue is due to the usage of

`commons.executeShellScriptFromFile`

If you try the [official step to execute shell](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) commands or scripts

```
def output = sh(returnStdout: true, returnStdoutTrim: true, script: 'cat foo.txt')
echo "Output: '${output}'"
```

The values are not printed.

#### Example

```
def bashScript = """
#!/bin/bash -xe
python3 running_myScript.py \${USERNAME} \${PASSWORD}                   
"""

def pythonScript = """
print("Im the python")
"""

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                script {
                    writeFile(file: 'run_shell_script.sh', text: bashScript)
                    writeFile(file: 'running_myScript.py', text: pythonScript)
                    
                    def USERNAME="foo"
                    def PASSWORD="bar"
                    sh "chmod +x run_shell_script.sh"
                    sh "./run_shell_script.sh"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

[image]

As you can see the log don't contains the sensible data, only the result of execution

```
Im the python
```

Comment: We’re trying to have all the of more commonly used functions (like: loading aws creds for certain account, run python script, run shell script, set up kubectl creds) all in a single place so that with withCredentials block is in that file (ie: the first code block i have with the function setupUserPWdVar)